# Html CSS not putting elements on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put two i elements on the same line.
    display: inline-block;
 does not seem to be working for this.
Here is my HTML

```css
#gamedesigner-topline {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ffb141;
  color: #fff;
  transition: color 0.3s;
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-size: 0px;
  margin: 3px 30px 15px;
  width: 180px !important;
  height: 180px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: normal;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background-image: none;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  left: 50px;
  background: #FAAC58;
}
#plugin-topline {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ffb141;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: initial;
  -moz-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: initial;
  transition-delay: initial;
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-size: 0px;
  margin: 3px 30px 15px;
  width: 180px !important;
  height: 180px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: normal;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background-image: none;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  left: 611px;
  background: #FAAC58;
}
.circles {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <a id="design">
    <i id="design-topline">
                            <img src="images\Home\designn.png">
                        </i>
  </a>
  <i id="plugin-topline">
                        <img src="images\Home\plugin.png">
                    </i>
</div>
```

With this CSS and HTML one circle is positioned exactly how I want it, on the left side of the screen. The second circle however is on the correct side of the screen that I want it, but seems to be a lot lower than the first circle, not on the same line. How would I get this circle on the same line as the first one. I am calling it a circle because this is what the CSS makes the i element turn out like.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle.net link of your code and paste the link.

Comment: reduce your css property for  #plugin-topline. First time I see 34line css for  a id.  give me the jsfiddle demo

Answer (score -1):

Change #plugin-topline's position to relative then adjust the position flags.

```
display: relative;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Try this

.circles {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #design-topline {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ffb141;
        color: #fff;
        transition: color 0.3s;
        display: inline-block !important;
        font-size: 0px;
        margin: 3px 30px 15px;
        width: 180px !important;
        height: 180px !important;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        line-height: normal;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background-image: none;
        background-position: 0% 0%;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        left: 50px;
        background: #FAAC58;
    }
    #plugin-topline {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ffb141;
        color: #fff;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-property: color;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: initial;
        -moz-transition: color 0.3s;
        transition: color 0.3s;
        transition-property: color;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-timing-function: initial;
        transition-delay: initial;
        display: inline-block !important;
        font-size: 0px;
        margin: 3px 30px 15px;
        width: 180px !important;
        height: 180px !important;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        line-height: normal;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background-image: none;
        background-position: 0% 0%;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        background: #FAAC58;
    }
```